# Is there a way to reposition an entire toolbar in FireFox 3.5?

Tags: firefox, user-interface

It seems like this should be simple, but I'm not finding an obvious way to do this.

I'd like to reorder the toolbars (not individual items) vertically.For example my toolbars are now displayed as such:

Navigation
Bookmarks
RoboForm
Google

I'd like to swap the position of Google and Bookmarks.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Drag'N'Drop toolbars extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3571).  This lets you do what you want to do.

[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in Firefox 3.5.

You can also accomplish what you want by editing the browser XUL manually.  The XUL you want to edit is `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`.   The files are kept in a JAR file in the Firefox install directory at `chrome/browser.jar`, which you will need to extract with a zip tool.  Look for the `<toolbox>` tag, and reorder the `<toolbar> (lots of stuff) </toolbar>` tags within to change the order of the toolbars.   After you are done, keep a copy of the old `browser.jar` for safekeeping, and zip up the directory structure again, and rename the zip file to a .jar.  (you also may want to simply "store" in the zip instead of compress, for speed).   I'm not sure how useful this will be in moving just ONE of the custom toolbars though, because it looks like they are grouped together in a `toolbarset` in the browser XUL.

Of course, this editing of the XUL is likely to get clobbered by an update, so you will have to do it over again.

Comment: Good answer. I also found this link (http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2009/06/how-to-move-unlock-firefox-toolbar/) that gives a little more context to the issue and also recommends this extension.

Comment: Ack! I had just upgraded to 3.5 to see if that helps, but unfortunately this extension doesn't support the new version yet.

Comment: edited this question to include a more complicated method of editing the XUL.  warning: for advanced users only! you can totally screw up your browser with this method.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rearrange extensions in **extensions.ini** file - in my case it helped to place "Google Toolbar" over "Web Developer" toolbar.

Location of file:

```
C:\Users\_user_\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xyz.default\extensions.ini
```

You have to change the numbered order, not just drag your preferred entry to the top of the list.

At the start of each line you'll see, respectively 'Extension0' then 'Extension1' etc. Change that final digit as required. Not all Extensions generate a Toolbar, of course, so in some instances the order may be irrelevant. I just made my Google toolbar '0', so I hope it'll always appear at the top.

I originally thought the physical order in the file was not important, but when I rebooted the computer and re-opened FF I found the extensions had re-ordered themselves. So now I've BOTH changed the numbering AND dragged them into the new order. I'm hoping this will work permanently. I'm working with FF14.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the area at the top near the location bar in FF and select "customize"

It is rather intuitive once you are in this mode.  Just go up and grab the bars you want to move around and put them where you want them.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not clicking in the right place, but every time I try to grab a toolbar it drags only the individual item on the toolbar. Are you sure about this approach?

Comment: You have to "unlock" it, check the other answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Tip: If you are not using all the buttons on Google Toolbar , Drag the Bookmark Toolbar onto Google Toolbar for saving space.

Saves one complete toolbar space!!

Comment: Good thought, but I am using a lot of buttons on both of those toolbars.